# jQuery: I dont understand what "i" is in .each(function(i)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand this jquery code, I understand all of it: the modulo, loop etc., except for what "i" means in .each(function(i). I've tried searching but this code doesn't return good search results. Does it represent each img that has an id of #photos? If so isn't that the same as the variable currentPhoto. Any help with understanding this or a link to useful info would be greatly appreciated.

```
function rotatePics(currentPhoto) {  //number is index of current photo
  var numberOfPhotos = $('#photos img').length;
  currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;

  $('#photos img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function() {
    // re-order the z-index
$('#photos img').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css(
    'zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos
  );
});
$(this).show();
setTimeout(function() {rotatePics(++currentPhoto);}, 4000);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
In case anyone going through the jquery: novice to ninja book has the same doubts:
(i) is 0 based and currentPhoto is 1 based, so for example the 1st img element would look like this(assuming there are 6 photos total):

```
((6        -       0) +      1        %     6
((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos
```

always adding 1 makes sure the remainder is always 1, thus making sure that the z-index is always 1.

Thanks for everybodies help!

Comment: Use the source Gertruder. (I just wanted to say that. First stop should generally be the documentation).

Comment: Hi pst - I know I did check out the documentation - I just dont understand if (i) is equivalent to "currentPhoto", if so why are they both necesary. If I'm keeping the z-index at "1" why couldn't I say: 'zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + i) % numberOfPhotos for example?

Comment: currentPhoto is needed for the loop. currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos; is a clever way of setting currentPhoto  back to 1 when it becomes larger than numberOfPhotos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i is the index position of the current element within the jquery collection

Comment: Thanks heroes twist, your comment above is definitely helpful in understanding. Can you tell me if the following code is the same as the original code? (switching out currentPhoto for "i": $(this).css(
    'zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + i) % numberOfPhotos
  );

Answer (score 5):

[The definition](http://api.jquery.com/each/) might help.

Comment: Ok, so i is "index"? a 0 based list of the elements? But isn't that the same as currentPhoto here? Is "i" essentially the same as "this" in $(this).css? Thanks for your help!

Comment: no 'this' is the actual element. i refers to the position of that element within the collection. i.e. the first img in the collection 1==0 the 2nd img i==1 e.t.c.

Answer (score 4):

each() function is documented here http://api.jquery.com/each/

By using jquery selectors you will have a list of objects, and i will be the index of these elements in dom creation order.

Answer (score 3):

'i' should represent the index within the loop.